# Is it possible to preserve the "coupling" between a system of differential equations when attempting to linearize one equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a system of equations of the form

$$\begin{bmatrix}
x'\\
y'
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} \\
a_{21} & a_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
1/y
\end{bmatrix}$$

This is a nonlinear system.

I noticed that equations of the form 
$$y' + P(t) y = Q(t) y^n$$ are called Bernoulli differential equations and can be linearized by setting $z' = y^{1-n}$ and then solving instead

$$z' + (1-n) P(t) z  = (1-n) Q(t)$$

I was wondering if, using this new $z$, there is a way to recover a system of equations the contains the information of my original system of equations?

For example, could I write something like

$$\begin{bmatrix}
x'\\
z'
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
b_{11} & b_{12} \\
b_{21} & b_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
z
\end{bmatrix}$$

and from this, would I be able to get the original dynamics I had in the first system somehow but now linearized?

Answer (score 1):

Actually the time dynamics of dynamical system can be described by a linear operator known as the Koopman operator, although this operator is typically infinite dimensional, even for finite-dimensional problems. Understanding and approximating this operator is a hot area in data-driven modeling.

As for explicit coordinate transforms that linearize an equation, these are quite rare in practice. This can sometimes be done using normal form theory, but often this is done to rewrite the nonlinearity in a more standard way. Linearization using normal form theory is still possible but only in certain circumstances iirc.